# Jmeter recording error 401

Tags: jmeter

I try to record my test with jmeter. So I configure my JMeter Script Recorder to use the port 8080. In my browser, i set the proxy to localhost 8080.
I my system.properties file, I set the proxy of my firm.

When I start the recorder and try to go on my site, I've the following error "Connexion reset". When I try to go on google I've the following error "content encoding error".

Do you have any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 401 stands for [Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) so my expectation is that your corporate proxy required valid credentials. As per [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) article you can pass username and password via `-u` and `-a` command-line arguments correspondingly.

> `-H` [proxy server hostname or ip address]
>
> `-P` [proxy server port]
>
> `-N` [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>
> `-u` [username for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> `-a` [password for proxy authentication - if required]

So you need to start JMeter like:

```
jmeter -H your_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port -u username -a password
```

Alternative option is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't need to worry about setting up proxies and SSL certificates.