# JMeter Script Recording - NTLM Windows Authentication Fails - 401 Error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

A JMeter script for an application needs to be recorded which has Windows Integrated authentication enabled and deployed on IIS. I am working behind VPN and having a hard time getting the script ready(using JMeter 5.3, Java – 1.8), a Sign In authentication pop up comes up every time I start recording and I am unable to proceed further.

I tried various options like

1. Setting up HTTP Authorization Manager to pass credentials as specified in the BlazeMeter guide but no luck.
2. I also tried changing HTTP Sampler Settings Type to Java as well as HTTPClient4 but none of them worked.
3. I did enable the setting “httpclient4.auth.preemptive=true” but this also did not help.
4. I found this article which explains [Jmeter recording error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973112/jmeter-recording-error-401) which suggests to configure **corporate_proxy_host** and start the JMETER using command

> "jmeter -H your_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port -u
> username -a password"

However, when I tried to identify the VPN IP/Hostname in ControlPanel --> Internet Options, I did not find this option enabled. And we connect to VPN using tool.

Is there any other way to identify "corporate_proxy_host", Moreover, should this option be considered?

[image]

My **Authorization Manager** has the following values:

•   Base URL: https:// [test site]
•   Username: [my user name]

•   Password: [my password]

•   Domain: company domain (checked using systeminfo.exe)

•   Mechanism: BASIC

However, I receive a 401 error (see Sampler Message below), Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Facing same issue any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong mechanism, for NTLM you need to use `BASIC_DIGEST`, the "Mechanism" is a dropdown:

[image]

also trying to recording NTLM login is not something you should really be doing, start your test with a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler opening your application main page and well-behaved HTTP Authorization Manager will deal with the authentication/authorization sides of things.

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

Comment: I tried this option of Basic_Digest too but this did not work. However, a sampler HHTP Request works with HTTP Authorization Manager. In addition to this, while debugging, I also realized in case of 401 error, Authorization Header is not present in the Request Headers but when I try some other token based application, it has Authorization Header present. Is it something that I should look further.